# Accessing Azure blob storage via REST using Coldfusion using C# example

Tags: c#, azure-storage, coldfusion-7

I've hit a brick wall trying to workout how to list all containers and blobs. Strangely enough i've not seen one Coldfusion example that does this.

I've tried following a C# project but i'm stuck at the point of creating a signature. The following is what i've extracted from the C# project so far.

resource array - these are some of the resources i'd like to invoke

1. restype=container&comp=list&include=snapshots&include=metadata
2. comp=list
3. container + "/" + blob + "?comp=pagelist
4. container + "/" + blob + "?comp=blocklist

What i've extracted from the C# logic

```
<cfhttp method="GET" url="http://#arguments.storageAccount#.#variables.hostEndPoint[storageType]#?#resource[1]#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-ms-date" value="#dateTimeString#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-ms-version" value="2009-09-19" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="??????" />
</cfhttp>
```

As im not a C# developer, If someone can explain what the outcome would be for the following i may be able to convert it.

Would MessageSignature be a comma delimited list of of the values below (i.e. '{0}\n\n\n{1}\n{5}\n\n\n\n{2}\n\n\n\n{3}{4},GET,,whatever ifMatch returns,...')

```
MessageSignature = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n{5}\n\n\n\n{2}\n\n\n\n{3}{4}",
    method,
    (method == "GET" || method == "HEAD") ? String.Empty : request.ContentLength.ToString(),
    ifMatch,
    GetCanonicalizedHeaders(request),
    GetCanonicalizedResource(request.RequestUri, StorageAccount),
    md5
);
```

What will the following return for an example string (e.g 'Complex Azure!')

```
    byte[] SignatureBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MessageSignature);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to play around with the REST API from Coldfusion a while ago without much success so I am not able to answer your question directly (I could not get the signature right either).  However, Microsoft now fully support an [Azure Java SDK](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) that uses the REST API and this should be consumable from Coldfusion (although I have not had a chance to try it yet - although I fully intend to).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Gary, i dont want to use the java sdk as im just looking to invoke one or two of the methods so it seems an overkill. So frustrating, that they made it so complicated and their documentation is far from self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a video showing How to access Azure REST API using C#, I'm sure the video could help you, java logic would be very similar.

http://youtu.be/NJQzEnk2Gck?hd=1

Answer (score 1):

I have been on the same quest for a while.

I just updated to CF 2021 to try get all those issues away.

There are new embeded features that may help: https://helpx.adobe.com/br/coldfusion/using/integrate-coldfusion-azure-blob.html